# Multiple Instances of the Same Type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

Using StructureMap, let's say I configure a couple of instances for a given interface, identified by names:

```
registry.For(interfaceType).Add(firstType).Named(firstName);
registry.For(interfaceType).Add(secondType).Named(secondName);
registry.For(interfaceType).Use(defaultType);
```

This works well for my needs.  However, in some application scenarios I have cause to override an instance to use the same concrete type as another instance.  So effectively going with something like this:

```
registry.For(interfaceType).Add(defaultType).Named(firstName);
registry.For(interfaceType).Add(defaultType).Named(secondName);
registry.For(interfaceType).Use(defaultType);
```

In practice, however, it would seem that StructureMap then uses not just the same type, but the same instance.  So there is exactly *one* instance of `defaultType` in memory, which the container supplies for any named request.

Is there a way to tell it to construct and use separate instances even when they're the same concrete type?

Comment: If I have understood [this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/07/20/StructureMapPerRequestvs.Uniquelifetimes/) correctly, the reason would be that by default the lifecycle is `PerRequest`, you would need to specify the lifecycle to be unique by doing something like `registry.For(interfaceType).Add(defaultType).Named(firstName).LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifecycle());`

Comment: @TI: It looks like that goes to the other extreme of the spectrum, supplying a new instance on every request.  What I'm looking to do is somewhere in between, some sort of unique-per-instance-name lifecycle.  I'm not finding anything like that yet, but you've definitely pointed me in a good direction.  Perhaps I can roll my own `ILifecycle`, or as a last resort internally track instances in my service locator implementation that sits between StructureMap and the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the behaviour I am seeing:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(cfg =>
{
    cfg.For<IFoo>().Add<Foo>().Named("Foo1");
    cfg.For<IFoo>().Add<Bar>().Named("Foo2");
    cfg.For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>();
});

var foo1 = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IFoo>("Foo1");
var defaultFoo = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IFoo>();

Debug.Assert(!Object.ReferenceEquals(foo1, defaultFoo));
```

Here the named instance and the default instances are *different*.

You are passing a type and not an object (which would be treated as singleton) in your StructureMap registration?